# First approach to build a multi-place booking system

Tags: architecture

I need a first approach to build a booking system that works with multiples places. The objetive is that system will be used by **many places**.

At the beginning I have decide to use a wheel already invented, there are many scripts built that sell you the code. The problem is that all of them are designed for one place only. So I have two options.

1. Modify the code to create a multi-place system (a lot of modifications I think).
2. Make one installation by place and manage this with a script (create a installation, create db, ...). Also I think to make a administration panel to manage all the installation and so on.

The project will be a web application powered by PHP.

The customers will apply a public form to make de booking, then each restaurant has got its own administration panel with its bookings.

What form would you choose?

Comment: What does the booking system do? Book what? Is it a web application or desktop application? Do users register themselves in the system? Are there payments involved?

Comment: @AseemBansal entry updated with more details

Comment: If any answer actually answers your question then you should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the 2nd form. Basically because that can get you started faster (it seems like that as per your comments that the first would require many changes). If you can get started faster you will know whether it works or not. Faster feedback is better.

The problems that you might face with this form would be payments, registrations but as users are going to use a public form to make the booking I am assuming that there are no registration or payments involved.

You wouldn't want the user to register for every place separately, would you? I will not want my customers to experience that. Similar concerns for payments.

Sit down and think what could be the things that would require any dependency among the various installations as per the business. What things will need to be shared by the various installations operation wise. You need to do this because having an idea of this would tell you whether you can actually automate everything or not. Installation, database with initial values can be automated but if operating the system would require many other common things that could become a concern.